# How pass a serializable object inside a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class call MyClass that implements Serializable, Cloneable with his strings, int, setters, getters methods.
Now, I have this two methods, in another class, that works fine separately.

1)

```
public void myStatus(final MyClass a, final boolean b) {
.
.
.
}
```

2)

```
public void secondStatust(final ArrayList<MyClass> as, final boolean b) {
.
.
.
}
```

That I want to do is call the method 2 inside the method 1, something like this:

```
public void myStatus(final MyClass a, final boolean b) {

        secondStatust(a, b);
}
```

But I can't do it, because the second method is waiting a ArrayLis....

Some suggestions??

Thanks in advance

Comment: In myStatus create an empty ArrayList, put 'a' in it end send it to secondStatust...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
public void myStatus(final MyClass a, final boolean b) {
    ArrayList<MyClass> arraylist = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    arraylist.add(a);
    secondStatust(arraylist, b);
}
```

Put the 'a' object in the arraylist object  and pass it to secondStatust

Answer (score 0):

You may also use *double brace initialization*, but be aware of the [downsides](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern):

```
 public void myStatus(final String a, final boolean b) {
    secondStatust(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add(a); }}, b);
 }
```

Downsides include:

- Bad readability
- Creation of a new (anonymous) type
- Risk for memory leaks